# How to create a simple DOM element within a constructor and append it to an element on invocation

Tags: javascript, dom, constructor

The comments should be self explanatory. I simply want to create an element in a constructor and have it appended to the DOM when an object is created with it.

```
<div id="app">

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function DomItem(name,buttonName,button){ 

if(typeof(this.button)==='undefined') {
    this.button  =   document.createElement('div');
};

this.buttonName = buttonName;
this.button.className = buttonName;
this.button.id = name +"_ " +buttonName;
var app = document.getElementById("app");   //Works!
console.log(app);                          // Works!
app.appendChild(button);                  // Problem ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~




};



osc = new DomItem('osc','button');
```

Comment: what kind of element is 'app' . are you sure you are not trying to appendChild to an element which does not support a div as a child?

Comment: Inside my constructor function I'm trying to reference a preexisting DOM element which is shown in the HTML code

Comment: If your code example, `button` is the third argument to the `DomItem()` constructor, but in your code example, you only pass two arguments to the constructor so the `button` argument is undefined.

Comment: The constructor sets a default definition to button using an if statement. Hence its not undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`button` within the `DomItem` constructor function is `undefined` since you are not passing in the third `button` parameter. Any named parameter that isn't passed is assigned the value `undefined`.

```
osc = new DomItem('osc','button'/*, button parameter missing*/);
```

Use `this.button` to refer to the button created within the constructor.

```
app.appendChild(this.button);
```

Note that `this.button` in the below code doesn't refer to the third `button` argument but to a property `button` of `this`, which will always be undefined on calling the constructor.

```
if(typeof this.button ==='undefined') {
    this.button = document.createElement('div');
}
```

Comment: Thanks the wording you used is confusing as I thought it was defined due to the if statement. The this.button makes sense and was a simple mistake. Thank you.